# Python Error TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects

Tags: python, string, concatenation

I am new with Python programming. I keep getting the below error on the 'str'.
When I added the + str, it didnt work.

```
wkt = "POINT("+ geoPoint["lat"] +" " + geoPoint["lon"] + ")"
```

---

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects
```

Any advice on how I can fix this error?

Comment: Don't try to concatenate `str` and `flloat` objects?

Comment: Don't learn the language by typing the code without understanding the meaning. Start with reading an excellent Python tutorial (included with any Python distribution, also available on python.org website).

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution would look like this:

```
wkt = "POINT("+ str(geoPoint["lat"]) +" " + str(geoPoint["lon"]) + ")"
```

The following would be more in line with accepted Python stylistic standards:

```
wkt = "POINT(%f %f)" % (geoPoint["lat"], geoPoint["lon"])
```

This uses the simplest form of [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

You could do something nicer still:

```
wkt = "POINT({lat} {lon}".format(**geoPoint)
```

See the linked page for more ideas on this.

Answer (score 2):

Not able to concatenate 'str' and 'float' with **'+'**

Best way to concatenate string and float in python.Use **format** function:

```
wkt = "POINT({} {})".format(geoPoint["lat"], geoPoint["lon"])
```

Also use:

```
>>>wkt = "POINT(%s %s)" % (geoPoint["lat"], geoPoint["lon"])
>>>'s'+2    # use like this.It will raise type error exception
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects
>>>'%s%s' % ('s', 2)
's2'
>>>'POINT({}{})'.format(geoPoint["lat"], geoPoint["lon"])
# It will print your value
```