# How to concatenate string to python data frame values with where condition

Tags: python, pandas

I want concatenate column: ['Time Period'] value and other string ('01-01') to new column: 'Date', with condition dt['Frequency']=='0'. Please help on this, I am new to python and learning scripting by some data processing.

```
dt.loc[dt['Frequency']=='0','Date']=dt['Time Period']+'01-01'

dt:
Frequency,Time Period,Date
0,2008
0,1961
2,2015Q1
3,2016M1
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43971280/python-error-typeerror-cannot-concatenate-str-and-float-objects/43971322#43971322) may help you.

Comment: @Mohammed Yasin, No... Data frame having column 'Time Period' & I want to update it in another column as per condition + '01-01'

Comment: can you please show your DataFrame, that will help me to solve answer.

Comment: @ammy updated, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df["Date"] = df.loc[df['Frequency']==0, 'Time Period'] +"01-01"
```

Answer updated

Comment: hey ammy can you explain what you've done here and what the original bug was? also don't think you need/want the first `dt["Date"] = '`

Comment: @ammy, done it: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."